# Get Unique rows using Entity framework

Tags: mysql, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am using 3 tables to set roles for users.

### 1. module

Id, Name

### 2. actions

Id ,  Name ,ModuleId (Foreign key with modules)

### 3. userActions

Id,UserId,ActionId (Foreign key with actions)

I want to get the unique list of modules for a user from the userActions table  . I am using Entity Framework and my database is Mysql
I used the query

```
var result = (from p in my_accountEntities.useractions
                      where p.UserId == item.Id
                      select p.action.module).ToList();

        List<module> modules = new List<module>();
        if (result != null)
        {
            modules = (List<module>)result;

        }
```

Its not returning a Unique list , but its returning all the rows in Useraction table.
How can i  get the unique list of  modules(based on moduleId)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the linq `.Distinct()` extension method

```
var result = (from p in my_accountEntities.useractions
                  where p.UserId == item.Id
                  select p.action.module)
                  .Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Yes it worked for me :).One more thing to ask 
Is there any known limitations of using Mysql with EntityFramework ?

Comment: I've only used MySQL on one project, but we didn't run into any major issues with it, may be best posed as another question that others with more experience can answer.